# Adicionar variável ao editor textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou usando o https://summernote.org/ para criar um editor de texto.

No momento da edição, é necessário adicionar variáveis, que no momento da impressão serão trocados pelo valor correspondente a cada variável.

Exemplo: A variável $eCNPJ, será substituta e ira aparecer o CNPJ correspondente.

**PROBLEMA:**

Ao clicar na variável, ela deveria aparecer no dentro do editor na posição marcada, isso não está acontecendo.

Parece que quando o código é executado no navegador, o id da textarea é alterado `<textarea id="editor1" class="form-control" name="texto"></textarea>`.

Até o momento não consegui resolver isso.

CÓDIGO:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#editor1').summernote({
    tabsize: 2,
    height: 200
  });
  
  

  $('.button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const editor = document.getElementById('editor1');
    const posicaoFinal = editor.selectionStart + this.innerText.length;

    editor.value =
      editor.value.slice(0, editor.selectionStart) +
      this.innerText +
      editor.value.slice(editor.selectionEnd);

    editor.setSelectionRange(posicaoFinal, posicaoFinal);
    editor.focus();
  });
  
});
```

```html
<!-- include libraries(jQuery, bootstrap) -->
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


<!-- include summernote css/js -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.12/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.12/summernote.js"></script>


<textarea id="editor1" class="form-control" name="texto"></textarea>

<br>

<small><strong>ESCOLA...:</strong>
  <a href="#" title="CNPJ" class="button">$eCNPJ</a>
  - <a href="#" title="Rasão Social" class="button">$eRSocial</a>
  - <a href="#" title="Nome Fantasia" class="button"> $eNFantasia</a>
  - <a href="#" title="E-mail" class="button"> $eEmail</a>
  - <a href="#" title="Telefone" class="button"> $eTelefone</a>
</small>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É isso que você precisa que aconteça?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#editor1').summernote({
    tabsize: 2,
    height: 200
  });
  
  

  $('.button').click(function(event) {
  
    event.preventDefault();
    
    $('#editor1').summernote('insertText', this.innerText);
   
  });
  
});
```

```html
<!-- include libraries(jQuery, bootstrap) -->
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


<!-- include summernote css/js -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.12/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.12/summernote.js"></script>


<textarea id="editor1" class="form-control" name="texto"></textarea>

<br>

<small><strong>ESCOLA...:</strong>
  <a href="#" title="CNPJ" class="button">$eCNPJ</a>
  - <a href="#" title="Rasão Social" class="button">$eRSocial</a>
  - <a href="#" title="Nome Fantasia" class="button"> $eNFantasia</a>
  - <a href="#" title="E-mail" class="button"> $eEmail</a>
  - <a href="#" title="Telefone" class="button"> $eTelefone</a>
</small>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Leon!

Comment: Eu usava esse código para colar texto sem formatação `document.querySelector("#editor1").addEventListener("paste", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");

    document.execCommand("insertText", false, text);
  });` mas depois que troquei o editor ele não cola mais sem formatação. Como posso modificar?

Comment: Dá uma olhada neste link: https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/303

Comment: Leon, uma dúvida, questão de estética... Ao adicionar a variável, como faço para que tenha um espaço na frete e atrás da variável?

Comment: $('#editor1').summernote('insertText', ` ${this.innerText} `);

Comment: Muito obrigado!